# If $\sum_{k \geq 0} c_k z^k $ has convergence radius R, what's $\sum_{k \geq 0} c_k z^{2k} $ conv. radius?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

If $\sum_{k \geq 0} c_k z^k $ has convergence radius R, what's $\sum_{k \geq 0} c_k z^{2k} $ radius of convergence?

I really have no clue how I proceed with this question.

Let's say $f(z) = \sum_{k \geq 0} c_k z^k $ converges for $ |z| < R $, then $ f(z^2) = \sum_{k \geq 0} c_k z^{2k} $ converges for $ |z^2| < R  \iff |z| < R$. Am I thinking correct?

What about, for example  $\sum_{k \geq 0} 3^k c_k z^k $?

$ |z| < R/3 $?

Comment: If the first series converges at $z$ you can plug a square root of that $z$ in the second series. It will converge, because you get the first series. Power series evaluated at points strictly outside its radius of convergence diverge due to their terms not tending to zero. If $z$ is a point strictly outside the radius of convergence of the first series then a square root of $z$ will have to be outside the radius of convergence of the second. Therefore, if $R$ is the radius of convergence of the first series, then $\sqrt{R}$ is that of the second series.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I initally wrote $ |z^2| < 1 $, hence I forgot the square root. Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788437