# How to use Cauchy Hadamard's Theorem in the case of irregular footmarks and exponents

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I know the situation when the exponents like $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n^2}$

> This is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$ with $$a_k=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }\exists >n\in\Bbb N,\, k=n^2\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> Therefore $\lvert a_k\rvert^{1/k}=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }\exists n\in\Bbb N,\, k=n^2\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ (for $k>0$). Therefore $\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}\lvert a_k\rvert^{1/k}=1$ and the radius of convergence is $1$.

But what if $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{kn}$ or $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_{n^2} x^n$.(k is a positive integer)

What is the difference about Region of Convergence and Radius of Convergence of Normal state and above state?

Comment: It can be partially solved by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788437/prove-the-radius-of-convergence-of-the-series-sum-k-1-inftya-kxn-k-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is the radius of convergence of $\sum a_nx^n,$ then the series $\sum a_nx^{kn}$ is convergent for $|x|^k<R$ and divergent for $|x|^k>R.$ Therefore the radius of convergence is equal $R^{1/k}.$

Concerning the series $\sum a_{n^2}x^n,$ in general there is no simple relation between its radius $R'$ of convergence and the radius $R$ of convergence of $\sum a_nx^n.$

**Observation**
The radius of convergence of the series $$\sum_n a_{n^2}x^{n^2}$$ is greater or equal $R.$ This follows from a general formula
$$R=\sup\{|x|\,:\, \lim_na_nx^n=0\}$$
Then for $|x|<R,$ we have $\displaystyle\lim_na_nx^n=0,$ hence
$\displaystyle\lim_na_{n^2}x^{n^2}=0.$

Assume $R>1.$ Fix $ y\in \mathbb{R},$  $|y|\ge  1.$ As $R^k$ tends to $\infty,$ when $k\to \infty,$ there exists $k_0,$ such that  $|y|\le R^{k_0}.$
Then for $x=|y|^{1/k_0}$ we have $1\le x<R.$ Furthermore for  $n\ge k_0$ we obtain $$|a_{n^2}|\,|y|^n= |a_{n^2}|\,x^{k_0n}\le |a_{n^2}|\,x^{n^2}$$ The series $\sum|a_{n^2}|\,x^{n^2}$ is convergent by the observation made earlier. Hence
by comparison test
the series
$\sum a_{n^2}y^{n}$ is absolutely convergent.
As $|y|\ge 1$ was arbitrary the radius of convergence of $\sum a_{n^2}y^n$ is infinite.

For $0<R\le 1$ there is no relation whatsoever.
For example let  $a_n=2^{-n^{2/3}}.$ Then $a_{n^2}=2^{-n^{4/3}}.$ We get $R=1$ and $R'=0.$ On the other hand for $a_{n^2}=0$ and $a_k=1$ for $k\neq n^2$ we get $R=1$ and $R'=\infty.$

Comment: I don’t understand “Therefore the series
$\sum a_{n^2}y^{n}$ is convergent if $|y|^{1/k}<R$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N},$ or equivalently if $|y|<R^k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}.$  Therefore $R'=\infty.$”.    Is this by comparison test ? Why $R'=\infty.$?

Comment: @liyushu I have re-edited the answer. It should be clearer now.